# How to print a binary number of a list with a given probability of error (Python)

Tags: python, list, printing, binary, probability

If I have a list of binary numbers (0 and 1). And I need to print these number with probability p (p= 1-probability of error in the channel).

If probability of error = 0.2 (p=0.8) and the secuence is 101010101010, the solution would be something like 101011101000...

---

```
Per = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de error: "))
while Per > 1 or Per < 0:
    print("P.error ha de tener un valor comprendido entre 0 y 1/2")
    Per = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de error: "))

q = 1 - Per
import random

entrada = int(input("Introduzca manualmente secuencia de bits: "),2)
bits = [int(x) for x in bin(entrada)[2:]]
```

Comment: Done! I have no error log... I dont know how to make the rest of the code...

Comment: how many decimal points does the error probability would be?

Comment: as many as the user wants to... He is who write the inputs...

Comment: In your example, the error probability is not accurate right, it's around 0.17. so, it is not a problem for you if there is such kind of approximation right?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the bits, and with each step generate a random values between 0 and 1. If your random value is less than q, you add the correct bit to your new list bits_con_error. If your random value is higher than q, then you add a randomly generated 1 or 0, using randint(0, 1)

```
Per = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de error: "))
while Per > 1 or Per < 0:
    print("P.error ha de tener un valor comprendido entre 0 y 1/2")
    Per = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de error: "))

q = 1 - Per
import random

entrada = int(input("Introduzca manualmente secuencia de bits: "),2)
bits = [int(x) for x in bin(entrada)[2:]]

bits_con_error = []
for bit in bits:
    if random.random() < q:
        bits_con_error.append(bit)
    else:
        bits_con_error.append(random.randint(0, 1))
print(bits_con_error)
```

Or if the error in the channel should flip the bit, instead of randomly generating a new bit, you can use `bits_con_error.append(int(not bit))`

Comment: THANK UUUUUUUUU!!!!! that is just what i wanted!! it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
tot = len(entrada)
approx= round(Per*tot)

temp = list(entrada)
entrada = list(entrada)
for i in random.sample(range(0,tot),approx):
  if entrada[i]=='1':
    entrada[i]='0'
  else:
    entrada[i]='1'

count = 0
for i in range(len(entrada)):
  if(temp[i]!=entrada[i]):
    count+=1

entrada =''.join(entrada)
print('modified entrada is : ',entrada)
print('error after modification is : ',round(count/len(entrada),3),' approximately..')
```

Output:

```
modified entrada is :  000111001011
error after modification is :  0.167  approximately..
```